# Какую версию laravel использовать для работы?

Tags: php, laravel

заметил что уже есть laravel v.6 , однако большинства проектов написаны и тем более пишут на 5.8. Подскажите есть какие то подводные камни с 6 версии? Или же можно смело на 6 версии писать

Comment: Новый проект нет смысла начинать на старой версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый достоверный источник, что нового, можно прочитать на [офсайте](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/releases)
Так же легко гугляться [ссылки и на русском языке](https://laravel.demiart.ru/laravel-6-whats-new/)
Для новых проектов, поддерживаю @Pavel, лучше использовать последнюю версию
Из подводных камней, по мне дак, это отсутствия какого-либо фронтенда по дефолту
Но это так же и плюс, теперь мы можем выбирать и не приходится выпиливать ненужное!